# Using multiple source files with rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have looked at multiple places (e.g. [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) and [Writing a package using Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf)) but failed to find a simple example for my problem.
What I need is to be able to use multiple cpp source files.
A simple example would be:
Lets say I have a pair of files: a.h, a.cpp which define the function f (which prepares some data for me).
Then I have b.cpp which includes a.h. What it does is define a function g which is exported to R (i.e. this is the only file which includes Rcpp.h). This function call f and then returns a data frame it created from f.

I need a way to compile a.cpp, link it to b.cpp (so it can call f) and then run g.
In practice, instead of a pair a.cpp, a.h I have a project i made externally (using a makefile on linux). The same files, however, should be compiled and linked to b.cpp on windows too (I know they compile properly using g++). When I created the makefile I added a couple of flags (several -I flags to define the include directories and several -D flags to define behavior).
I cannot really touch the original project though, only b.c and adding external files.
I was looking for a simple way to accomplish this. The closest I saw was creating a package which includes the files using  Rcpp.package.skeleton. There are a couple of problems with this approach though:

1. I need to reference the relevant files but Rcpp.package.skeleton copies them. The most of the cpp files (i.e. everything note related to R) belong to a different project which has its own position in our repository and I do not want to touch them (i also cannot use soft links because we use a mixed environment of windows and linux).
2. I prefer not to create a separate package as it seems to be a little complex for my simple needs

I saw that it is possible to link an external library but I have no idea how to compile it in a way which is compatible to R (especially in windows).

The only simple solution I found so far is to include all relevant cpp files directly into the R related cpp (i.e. add a #include "a.cpp" at the beginning of b.cpp as the list of files would not really change and I don't mind if everything compiles every time) and do a Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"=myflags) before using sourceCpp.

I would prefer finding a more elegant (and not too complex) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the possibility of having your header files in `mypackage/inst/include` so that they get installed in `mypackage/include`.

Subsequent use can simply have a `LinkingTo: mypackage`, or `Depends` attribute.  Look for example and the numerous RcppArmadillo-using examples in the Rcpp Gallery or here -- none copy files.

Comment: From my understanding LinkingTo only works if the other files are in an R package. The cpp files in my case are not, they are in a separate directory (for which I have both a visual studio project and a linux makefile).

Comment: You failed to explain why you cannot just create a library.

Comment: how do I create a library which is compatible with R? in windows I usually use visual studio and in linux I create a .a with its own logic (no R related flags). Do I just use a regular linux makefile to create a regular .a library?

Comment: that is the question. Is a regular library enough or do I need a special means of doing so? i.e. lets say I compile and create a .a library regularly (i.e. without anything to do with R). Do I just need to do Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"=="-L/myPath -lmylib -Imypath_to_include") with any precompiled .a library?

Comment: Yes. `PKG_CXXFLAGS` for includes (your last part), `PKG_LIBS` for libraries (ie `-l...` and `-L...`).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Could you come down to the level of the little people and provide a more detailed answer with more detailed examples or links to examples?

Comment: It is difficult to summarize [an entire manual](https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-exts/) on extending R and packages, or a set of [ten vignettes for Rcpp](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html), or a set of [near;y 3000 other Rcpp answers here](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html)  into few words.  At least I cannot do it.  Sometimes you need to buckle up and learn by reading, experimenting, reading some more, ...